# What is the Linux capability(7) to write to /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$IF/disable_ipv6?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-capabilities

I've got a test that I'm writing for a larger program that needs to (1) create a tap device, (2) bind a raw socket, and (3) make a sysctl to disable IPv6.  I'm writing to find the set of Linux capabilities to do all of these things so I don't have to run the test as root.   The first two are easy: CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW, but try as I might, I cannot seem to figure out the capability needed to run:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$if/disable_ipv6   # e.g., for 'if=eth0',etc.
```

I've tried CAP_SYS_ADMIN and CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE and neither of those are sufficient.  I've tried to read through the kernel source but am not making headway, so I'm going to cop out and ask for help.

Thank you in advance!

[edit]

```
$ getcap ./target/debug/deps/tap_tests-e43c717a6e86b805
./target/debug/deps/tap_tests-e43c717a6e86b805 
cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_admin=eip
$ ./target/debug/deps/tap_tests-e43c717a6e86b805
[snip]
--- test_conntrack_active_probe stdout ----
thread 'test_conntrack_active_probe' panicked at 'safe_run_command FAILED: 'sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.testtap1.disable_ipv6=1' command returned stderr 'Ok(
    "sysctl: permission denied on key \"net.ipv6.conf.testtap1.disable_ipv6\"\n",
)'', tests/tap_tests.rs:275:13
```

Also, I had to do this to debug:

```
$ cp `which strace` ./strace
$ setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN=epi ./strace
$ ./strace -f <test>     # normal strace doesn't inherit the test's capabilities
```

Posting here in case it helps others.

[edit2]

It looks like this is the core problem/solution:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128394/passing-capabilities-through-exec

Comment: How are you applying the capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like only `CAP_NET_ADMIN` is necessary.

We can verify that using a simple C program that, given a list of interfaces as arguments, sets the `disable_ipv6` sysctl for each interface:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SYSCTL_TEMPLATE "/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/%s/disable_ipv6"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int template_len = strlen(SYSCTL_TEMPLATE);

    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        int path_len, fd, nb;
        char path[1024];

        printf("interface name: %s\n", argv[i]);
        path_len = template_len + strlen(argv[i]);
        if (path_len > 1024) {
            fprintf(stderr, "path too long\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        sprintf(path, SYSCTL_TEMPLATE, argv[i]);
        
        if ((fd = open(path, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
            perror("open");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ((nb = write(fd, "1", 1)) < 0) {
            perror("write");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm going to be using an interface named `vlan1` as my test interface; initially, it looks like:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.vlan1.disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.vlan1.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

If I run the compiled binary as a normal user, it fails with a "permission denied" error:

```
$ ./disable_ipv6 vlan1
interface name: vlan1
open: Permission denied
```

If I set the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability on this binary:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_admin+eip disable_ipv6
```

And then re-run it, it succeeds:

```
$ ./disable_ipv6 vlan1
interface name: vlan1
```

After which we can see the value of the sysctl has been modified:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.vlan1.disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.vlan1.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

---

If your goal is explicitly to set this sysctl using `echo`, then you'll need to arrange to run a shell with the necessary privileges. It looks like we can do this using the `--addamb` option to `capsh` (to add the capability to the ambient capability set):

```
$ sudo env HOME=$HOME capsh --user=$USER --inh=cap_net_admin --addamb=cap_net_admin --
```

This gives us the necessary capability set:

```
$ getpcaps $$
1496078: cap_net_admin=eip
```

And allows us to modify the desired sysctl without errors:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vlan1/disable_ipv6
$ echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/vlan1/disable_ipv6
```

Comment: IMHO, very worthy of adding this to your blog. Good luck to all!

Comment: Hmm.  My test is a compiled rust binary and I'm setting capabilities with setcap:

$ getcap ./target/debug/deps/tap_tests-e43c717a6e86b805
./target/debug/deps/tap_tests-e43c717a6e86b805 cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_admin=eip

And in the code, I'm calling execve() to call sysctl manually.  I had thought the 'effective' perm in "=epi" should transfer to child processes but that seems to be the problem.  I can just rewrite so that my test natively opens the file rather than exec()'ing sysctl.

Comment: Also - THANK YOU!  Your C code works as advertised on my system so the problem must be with my test code somewhere.  Very odd that the capability doesn't transfer with the exec().  

Also, I had to do this to debug:
```
$ cp `which strace` ./strace
$ setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN=epi ./strace
$ ./strace -f <test>     # normal strace doesn't inherit the test's capabilities
```
Posting here in case it helps others.